# Font making another effect when hovering which is changing the size

Tags: html, css, sass

I create a button in which I would like to transform its scale. But when I hover over the button the font of it changes size in the last seconds which makes it a little larger. What can I do about this?

Code below

**HTML:**

```html
<button>Generate password</button>
```

**SCSS:**

```scss
button{
  background-color: #10B981;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  padding: 0.6em;
  margin-top: 3em;
  border: none;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    
  &:hover{
    transform: scale(0.90);
  }
}
```

Comment: To clearly show what I'm asking about here's the video.
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LFfCyDHfai86rSsfoc1tUvDmAIe_GBG9/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score -1):

You need to

```
button{
    background-color: #10B981;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    padding: 0.6em;
    margin-top: 3em;
    border: none;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
button:hover{
    transform: scale(0.9);
}
```

You can take a look at: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_zoom_hover.asp

Comment: OP clearly stated and flagged to use SASS.